# Can builder modify the bundle in PBS?

Tags: flashbots

If I send a transactions bundle to a specific builder, can they add a new transaction in my bundle to attack me? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You bundle transacation has been signed with private key, so decrypt a signed transacation bundle same as crack a wallet